# Swap ERC20 -> BEP2

Tags: erc-20, swaps

Just like the title says, how can I do it? I forgot to leave some BNB in the wallet and can't pay for the gas so I need to fund it back before I miss what I think is a good coin.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible without paying for the gas to move the tokens.

Comment: @Ismael that's fine, I can pay the gas fee, how can I do it?

Comment: Just move the tokens to an exchange that support both tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered this simple question I'll do it. For new comers, what you have to use is a bridge. For example Binance has a bridge to convert ERC20 to PEB2 tokens, the bridge is made by the Blockchain devs, for example Polygon has another bridge to convert Tokens from the ETH blockchain to theirs.